# Convert (x,y) to Grid Coordinates

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Let's say I have a 2D-space from x=0 to x=1, and y=0 to y=1. Additionally, I have a grid (i,j)  of rectangles with size 1/3, starting at (0,0), that subdivides the space into 9 grid cells. How can I convert some coordinate (x,y), e.g., (0.3, 0.6) into grid coordinates (i,j)?

I think it should be some combination of division by grid cell size and rounding but I can't find the correct rule.

Comment: What is the grid coordinate of `(0.3, 0.6)`?

Comment: do you want (0.3, 0.3) to be (1,1)(in terms of (i,j)? and (0, 0.3) to be (0,1)(in terms of (i,j))?

Comment: I want (0.3, 0.3) to be (0, 0) because 0 < 0.3 < 1/3 for both coordinates.

Comment: It seems quite strange this is the only visible question on Google that actually answers the problem of (coordinates => sector). So I don't really understand who downvoted here.

Comment: Thanks, DarioOO. Probably someone thought it is a question with an obvious answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, you want to find the closest grid point to a given point. Eg For (0.3,0.6) you want (1/3,2/3). Am I right?

If that is your problem, solution is (ROUND(x*3)/3, ROUND(y*3)/3).

UPDATE: You are looking for (FLOOR(x*3)/3, FLOOR(y*3)/3).

Comment: I want to find the grid cell in which a given point lies. (0.3,0.6) lies in the cell that starts at (0, 1/3) because 0 < 0.3 < 1/3 and 1/3 < 0.6 < 2/3.

Comment: @ArminMeisterhirn In that case you should be using function FLOOR instead of ROUND.